# Python 3.9 if a string matches a class name, instantiate the class (instantiate a specific class dynamically)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

I would like to instantiate a single class if a string var matches the name of the class.  In similar questions, there seems to be a dependency that the name of the class is known at the start.  In my case, I only know that the input string will match the name of a class.  I want to use the string to identify which class (out of many choices) I need to instantiate.  I.E. load the class with the same name as the string;

`If string-var == a class (in a module file) in a directory, instantiate that class.`

I thought the new getattr would help, but that seems to be for methods/functions as opposed to a class itself.  I also considered issubclass, but the parameter needs to be a class, not a string.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly define an interface that maps a publicly known string to a reference to the class:

```
class Foo:
    ...

class Bar:
    ...

classes = {"foo": Foo, "bar": Bar}
```

Then you can lookup the appropriate class in the dict using your string (which, as you'll note, is not required to be the name of the class):

```
cls_name = "foo"

obj = classes[cls_name]()
```

Comment: Thanks! Had to remove the (), so the final assignment is ```obj = classes[cls_name]```.  Can't say I understand why, but it is working that way.